# Laravel - CMS for certain pages

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm having an issue with figuring out the best approach for a requirement for a project.

There are a whole bunch of `routes`/ `resources` that currently exist in the system. I'm developing a CMS for some of the pages but all of the current pages MUST stay as `resources` and all contain the same functionality as before.

Here are the steps I want to achieve:

```
1. User enters `/users` 
2. Checks to see if `/users` is inside the `Pages` table
   -> No - (Return the Route::resource('/users))
   -> Yes - Returned `Dynamic.blade.php` with the content from the table.
```

The that I'm having is not being able to return the `Route::resource` since I could return the view itself, if the requested page is not within the table however, I'm unsure whether or not it's possible to return the `Resource` for the particular end-point if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your the controller associated with your `Route::resource('users', 'ControllerName')`, in the index function you can do something like this:

```
public function index(){
    // Obviously write your own condition logic here
    if('/users' in Pages table){
        // Returned `Dynamic.blade.php` with the content from the table.
    }
    else{
        // Do the other stuff you need to accomplish.
    }
}
```

If this wasn't what you were asking, please comment so I can better help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking more of doing it at the `routes` level since I see how this would work, however, there would be so much code duplication - right? I mean, for each controller I would have to essentially replicate this. Is there no way I can listen out for the `index` method being entered?

Comment: At the route level, you can define beneath your `Route::resource()` a `Route::get('users', function(){})` to override the `resource` method call. If I'm correct though you are specifically wanting to listen for the `UsersController@index` method (or whatever you've named it) to be called though? I'm looking into this now, but I've not encountered such a need in my own experience. Will you be duplicating the the @index for each individual resource controller? If so you could implement a trait or other class to prevent code duplication. (Sorry this is such an extensive comment)

Comment: I've looked around a bit, and I think if you absolutely need to listen at the route level your best option may be to create an event listener for when a route gets resolved. Similar code example here (layer7): https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/how-tocount-every-time-a-route-is-called